# Reduce array of closures into single closure

Tags: swift, closures, higher-order-functions

Suppose I have an array of closures which can all be composed with one another (i.e., endomorphisms, their input and output types are the same). How can I compose these closures into a single closure?

For reference, I was trying to design something like the following.

```swift
struct MyType {
    typealias MyClosure: (T) -> T
    private var myClosures: [MyClosure] = [ ... ]
    public var closure: MyClosure {
        get {
            return ? // somehow compose all of myClosures into a single closure here
        }
    }
}
```

My first thought was to use `reduce`, à la `myClosures.reduce(STARTING) { a, b in b(a) }`,
but this requires a starting value to be supplied, and then successively applies the closures to it. I don't want to apply the closures to anything (yet), but just synthesize the private list of closures into a single, public closure which can be applied later. Given the way `reduce` is
defined, I expect this would look something like

```swift
myClosures.reduce(identity) { a, b in compose(a, b) }

func identity(_ input: T) { return input }

func compose(a: MyClosure, b: MyClosure) -> MyClosure { return b(a) }
```

but the type of `b(a)` is `T`, not `(T) -> T`. How can this be accomplished? Is this a better way of going about closure composition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: My original answer misunderstood what your problem was. But seeing as my original answer might be useful to future readers, I'll leave it at the bottom.

Your `compose` function is nearly there! `b(a)` does not compile because `MyClosure` does not take another `MyClosure`. `b(a)` is *invoking* the closure ("function application"). not composition. Since `compose` returns a closure, why not return a closure? A typical closure looks like this in Swift:

```
{ (param) in return doSomethingTo(param) }
```

So let's return that!

```
return { (x) in return b(a(x)) }
```

This can be simplified to:

```
{ b(a($0)) } // "return" can be omitted as well!
```

[This page](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html) (among other things) tells you how and when you can simplify closure syntaxes.

---

Original answer:

Using `reduce` is the correct choice here. The reduction operation is *composition*, so let's write a `compose` function first:

```
func compose<T>(_ x: @escaping (T) -> T, _ y: @escaping (T) -> T) -> (T) -> T {
    { y(x($0)) } // or { x(y($0)) } if you want it the other way
}
```

Then, we `reduce`. What's the identity? The identity is something that has these properties:

```
compose(identity, anything) == anything
compose(anything, identity) == anything
```

What function does that? The identity function!

So we get:

```
func reduceClosures<T>(_ closures: [(T) -> T]) -> (T) -> T {
    closures.reduce({ $0 }, compose)
}
```